# iBeacon notification data comes unreadable?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, uart, hm-10

I am using a HM-10 (v709) as a master, with a Arduino. I want to get a value from a iBeacon's notification.

I connect to the iBeacon and turn on notifications for the characteristic, but the notifications I receive look like this: `⸮` or `⸮` or `x⸮⸮⸮⸮` or just question marks, depending on the serial rate of my monitor.

edit: There are four square characters in the first two code snippets above along with a question mark, which don't appear on stackoverflow for me.

Any ideas on what I should do? What kind of data I am receiving or what the problem may be? The data from the notification should look similar to this `0x04020311870100`.

Edit: When I send a AT command to read RD characteristics I get the correct data (such as manufacturers name, version, etc) that come as strings, but the hex values are what don't work. I am experimenting with this.

Comment: It would be helpful it you connect the dots about how you get from a HM-10 iBeacon transmission to unexpected characters in a “beacon’s notification.”  On what device do you see this notification?  What specifically do you mean by the term notification?  How does the notification get to your display from a Bluetooth transmitter?  How does a “characteristic” (which is a very distinct Bluetooth construct from iBeacon) come into play?

Comment: I have the HM-10 connected to a Arduino nano which is connected to my computer. I use   AT commands via Arduinos serial monitor. I do a minor setup then connect to the iBeacon then write the AT Command ```AT+NOTIFY_ON0017``` for the notify characteristic on the iBeacon (0017) and I start receiving the notifications ~ but they are not in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent hours troubleshooting to finally realize Arduino's serial monitor is unable to display raw hex values hence the undreadable characters. To solve this I used a different terminal https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/ which allows me to switch to HEX.